# Несколько доменых имен, с разными приложениями на одной машине

Tags: nginx, docker, ip, hosts

Есть приложения на php,mysql,nginx, работающее в связке контейнеров Docker. К приложению можно обратиться локально, условно говоря 127.0.0.1:8080. Есть также другое приложения на node js,тоже в Docker контейнере и висящее например на  127.0.0.1:8085. Ip адрес машины внешний, ну пусть будет 87.250.250.240.

Вопрос мой таков?? Внешние домены я могу направить на 87.250.250.240,чем осуществлять маршрутизацию на локальные хосты, еще один nginx поднимать? и как то распределять? или какие то другие вещи в linux есть.?

Comment: да, nginx или любой другой прокси, который будет перенаправлять трафик на основании host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поднимайте Nginx, который будет выполнять функцию проксирования. Фрагменты конфига:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
    }
}
```

Лучше не открывать порты приложений 8085 и 8080, а использовать имена контейнеров или сервисов вот так `proxy_pass http://nodejs:8085`

Comment: О это уже более по детальней, дальше уже слеплю, и нарою, спасибо!!